# gnuplot: How to create colored grid regions, not just colored grid lines?

Tags: colors, grid, gnuplot, area

I am using "gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2". I am trying to create background grid colored-columns or colored-areas like the picture below. So far, I am only able to color the grid-lines. But I want to color the grid areas. What is the best way? Here is my code:

```
set terminal svg 
set output 'out.svg'
set key off  
set xlabel 'X'
set ylabel 'Y'
set title 'Data'

set grid
set grid xtics  lw 0.25 lc rgb "#ff0000" # line only, but I want to color the whole area
#unset grid
#set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#0000ff"

set xrange [0:4]
set yrange [0:100]
set tics scale 0.5
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set style fill solid noborder
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'red' lw 0.35
set linetype 2 lc rgb '#009900' 
set linetype 3 lc rgb 'black' lw 0.5
set boxwidth 0.5 relative 
set style fill solid border lc rgb "black" 
plot "data.txt" using 1:2:4:3:5:($5 < $2 ? 1 : 2)  linecolor variable with candlesticks, \
     "data.txt" using 1:6 with lines lt 3, \
     "data.txt" using 1:5:7 with filledcurves fs transparent solid 0.3 lc rgb "blue"
```

And here is my sample data.txt file for the plotting:

```
1 10 30  5 20 23 29
2 25 45 10 30 34 37
3 30 50 20 25 47 53
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dummy function like `[x=0:16:1] '+' us (x/2):(100/(int(x)%4!=1)) with filledcurves x1`.
Every fourth point generates a `NaN` and interrupts the curve.

```
$data <<EOD
1 10 30  5 20 23 29
2 25 45 10 30 34 37
3 30 50 20 25 47 53
5 10 30  5 20 23 29
7 25 45 10 30 34 37
8 30 50 20 25 47 53
EOD

set style fill solid noborder
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'red' lw 0.35
set linetype 2 lc rgb '#009900' 
set linetype 3 lc rgb 'black' lw 0.5
set boxwidth 0.5 relative 
set style fill solid border lc rgb "black" 
plot sample [x=0:16:1] '+' us (x/2):(100/(int(x)%4!=1)) with filledcurves x1 fc rgb "#EEEEEE",\
     $data using 1:2:4:3:5:($5 < $2 ? 1 : 2)  linecolor variable with candlesticks, \
     $data using 1:6 with lines lt 3, \
     $data using 1:5:7 with filledcurves fs transparent solid 0.3 lc rgb "blue"
```

[image]

This function could be also assigned to the `y2` axis with fixed `y2range`, which might be more handy for interactive plots with zooming.

Comment: Thank you very much Friedrich !!! However, on my system, the colored areas are narrow bands clustered on the left. I will do some debugging. Thanks again !!!